# Is there a way to get all the request headers in a jQuery $.ajax call?

Tags: jquery, http-headers

I'm building a debug tool for AJAX requests, and I'd like to show the request/response headers (much like Firebug does). I can get the response headers using [jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-getallresponseheaders-method), but is there an equivalent for the **request headers**?

---

If not, I know I can somewhat reconstruct it myself:

```
GET /blah  // this part is easy
Host: servername.com  // pretty easy
Accept:  ???
Referer: ??? // just use current page url?
User-Agent:  // easy from navigator.userAgent
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest   // hardcoded, $.ajax always does this?
Accept-Charset: ???
Accept-Encoding: ??? 
Accept-Language: ???
Connection: ???
```

I care mostly about `Accept`. It seems the browser or something is changing this, since I am setting  `$.ajax({dataType:'json'})` and in firebug I see `Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01`. I'd like to be able to capture the actual header being sent.

For `Referer`, is it safe to just use window.url, or could it be something else?

I have no idea how to get the `Accept-*` or `Connection` values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get SENT headers in an XMLHttpRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564007/get-sent-headers-in-an-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer - surprisingly, no.

The [XMLHttpRequest API](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) doesn't have a method to retrieve the headers of the request about to be sent. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564007/get-sent-headers-in-an-xmlhttprequest).

The new [jqHXR object, a superset of the browser's native XMLHttpRequest](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), unfortunately doesn't implement one either.

The [`.ajaxComplete()` callback](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) does get a `settings` parameter which will contain the `headers` key if you've set it the normal way, but not if you've used [`.beforeSend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) to call [`setRequestHeader()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader()-method).

Answer (score 5):

You can use "this" as a reference for the current ajax request then get the property "accepts" like so :

```
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                url:'ajax.php',
                data:my_data_array,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(this.accepts);
                }
           });
```

Answer (score -6):

You can use the jqXHR object in the success function to access the headers.

```
$.ajax({
...
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR ){
console.log(jqXHR);
...
}
})
```

from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: As of jq 2.0.3, you can get *response* headers (via `getAllResponseHeaders()` or `getResponseHeader()`) but not *request* headers as I was asking for.