# How to print the values of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, rest, xmlhttprequest

I'm currently working with REST apis in JavaScript and I'm wondering if there is a way of displaying/printing the actual `request` or more precisely the `request header` what is called the `HTTP-Post request` that got send by the `XMLHttpRequest()`.

I'm not talking about the `response`. I'm talking about the `HTTP-Post`. E.g.:

```
POST /path/etc/etc HTTP/1.1 
Accept: application/json 
Content-Type: application/json 
custom-header-1: foo
custom-header-2: bla 
User-Agent: 1234 
Content-Length: 2 
Host: example.api.com 
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

that got send from e.g. this code:

```
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://example.api.com/path/etc/etc/";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept",                      "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type",                "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("custom-header-1",             "foo");
xhr.setRequestHeader("custom-header-2",             "bla");
xhr.send(requ);
//...
</script>
```

Is there a way of automatising this to determine if really the correct values got send?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get SENT headers in an XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564007/get-sent-headers-in-an-xmlhttprequest)